# Force order sync from the backlog overview to the board in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, scrum

As a Product Owner I'm responsible for the order of all items on the backlog. I order them through the backlog view. It looks like this at the moment:

[image]

What's annoying me to no end is the fact that this order is not 'linked' to the order of stories on the backlog lane on the board. When I prioritize stories and/or features in the backlog view, I want the stories from the board to follow that.

How do I achieve this?

**Edit: Further explanation**

We're using Kanban as a method. I want the backlog at Backlogs > Backlog as a whole synced towards the Boards > Backlog lane. In the Backlog we use 3 levels, epics, features and users stories (for example). In the Backlog lane in Boards, we only display the user stories. Now the order of those user stories are the problem. If I prioritize a feature differently (on the Backlog), I want all stories connected to that also move up or down on that Backlog lane.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot it looks like you are prioritizing the Product backlog (Azure DevOps - Boards > Backlog > [Specifics] - view as Backlog). When wanting the changes to reflect within the "Backlog lane of the board" do you mean:

- Product backlog Kanban board
  (Boards > Backlog > [Specifics] - view as Board))?
- Sprint Taskboard (Boards > Sprints > Taskboard)?

From here on out I will assume you are referring to the later (Sprint Taskboard) and that Product Backlog has been selected (Boards > Boards - view as Backlog).

Azure DevOps functionality typically follows the other direction. Changes in prioritization within the Sprint backlog (Boards > Sprints > Backlog) are synced "up" to the Product backlog (Boards > Boards - view as Backlog) as well as laterally within Sprint Taskboard (Boards > Sprint > Taskboard). For example, for Sprint 1 all User Stories associated with Feature A are added to the Sprint (5 User Stories total). After sprint planning, User Story number 5 is now number 1. Within the Sprint backlog, you update the order to reflect this. This change will be reflected laterally to the Sprint Taskboard, but also be reflected "up" to the Product backlog.

Option: Prioritize using Sprint backlog (Boards > Sprints > Backlog) instead of Product backlog (Boards > Boards - view as Backlog). Implies that changes made to order of User Stories are reflected in the Taskboard.

If this was not the correct syncing assumption, please update the question. If it was the correct syncing assumption, but an unsatisfactory answer (not over throwing Sprint to Product syncing) maybe another has the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not using sprints since we're using Kanban as a method. I mean Backlogs > Backlog as a whole synced towards Boards > Backlog lane. On the Backlog lane on the Backlog we use 3 levels, epics, features and users stories (for example). On the Backlog lane in Boards, we only display the user stories. Now the order of those user stories are the problem. If I prioritize a feature differently, I want all stories connected to that also move up or down on that Backlog lane. I've updated my question with this info